# How to Convert Multiple Raster in to NettCDF in Arcmap 10.1?

Tags: raster

My name is Paresh Chaudhary and I've worked in the field of Geometics since 2008. I have 30 day by day surface temperature images of MODIS, aqua satellite. Now i want to convert it into a NetCDF raster in ArcMap 10.1. I know one tool, ***Raster to NetCDF*** in **Multidimension Tools** tool set which does this but you can't input multiple images. So is it possible to convert 30 temperature variables into NetCDF raster? I would like to visualise all images with time and also perform temporal analysis.

Thanks a lot in advance